# Create SQL table with the data from another table

Tags: sql

How do I create a table using data which is already present in another table (copy of table)?

Comment: What RDBMS? There isn't a standard way.

Comment: I assume you have the data. Not sure if you have access to metadata to copy the table structure or you want to infer the table structure from a sample of content. Also, is is not defined what database you use.

Answer (score 25):

The most portable means of copying a table is to:

1. Create the new table with a CREATE TABLE statement
2. Use INSERT based on a SELECT from the old table:

   ```
   INSERT INTO new_table
   SELECT * FROM old_table
   ```

In SQL Server, I'd use the INTO syntax:

```
SELECT *
    INTO new_table
  FROM old_table
```

...because in SQL Server, the INTO clause creates a table that doesn't already exist.

Comment: Good answer, specially the sql server part as well which I was specifically looking for.

Answer (score 21):

If you are using MySQL, you may want to use the `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT` syntax to create a table defined by the columns and  data types of another result set:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT * 
FROM   old_table;
```

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE old_table (id int, value int);

INSERT INTO old_table VALUES (1, 100), (2, 200), (3, 300), (4, 400);

CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT * 
FROM   old_table;


SELECT * FROM new_table;
+------+-------+
| id   | value |
+------+-------+
|    1 |   100 |
|    2 |   200 |
|    3 |   300 |
|    4 |   400 |
+------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)


DESCRIBE new_table;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| value | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

For other DBMSes, that do not support this syntax, you may want to check out [@OMG Ponies' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382849/sql-table-creation/3382872#3382872) for a more portable solution.

Comment: @Renuka: If you like an answer, consider voting for it using the arrows to the left.  You can "accept" the answer you like most using the green V.

Comment: @DanielVassallo What if source table present in different database ? 
I also asked similar question but with different usecase - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351206/how-to-create-table-structure-in-rds-similar-to-source-table-in-redshift-and-vic

Answer (score 8):

For SQL Server

```
SELECT * 
INTO NewTable
FROM OldTable
```

Comment: What if OldTable present in different database ?
Can you please answer this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351206/how-to-create-table-structure-in-rds-similar-to-source-table-in-redshift-and-vic

Comment: You can also select specific columns (instead of `SELECT *`), and the new table will be created with only those specified columns.

Answer (score 2):

For Sql server:

Create new table from existing table :

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name AS 
SELECT [col1,col2,...coln] FROM existing_table_name [WHERE condition];
```

Insert values into existing table form another existing table using  **Select**  command :

```
SELECT * INTO destination_table FROM source_table [WHERE conditions];

SELECT *
INTO newtable [IN externaldb]
FROM oldtable
[ WHERE condition ];
```

Insert values into existing table form another existing table using 
 **Insert**  command :

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1,column2, column3, ... FROM table1 [WHERE condition];
```

Comment: The data transfer is good but I think Renuka needs also the table structure.

Comment: exact schema of existing table to new table : create table new_table_name like Old_table_name;

Answer (score 0):

if u want  **exact schema of existing table to new table**  and all values of existing table want to be inserted into your new table then execute below two queries :

```
create table new_table_name like Old_table_name;

select * into new_table_name from Old_table_name;
```

**LIKE** works only for base tables, not for views.

If the original table is a TEMPORARY table, CREATE TABLE ... LIKE does not preserve TEMPORARY. To create a TEMPORARY destination table, use CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ... LIKE.

[for more details click here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-like.html)

Answer (score 0):

had a similar question with a bit requiring a detail. So I'll expand on your question and deliver an answer for the expanded version of your question that goes as follows:

**EXPANDED QUESTION:**

*"How do I create a table using **partial** data which is already present in another table and index it with an added **automatic increment column** for a primary key?"*

**USE CASE:**

When normalizing a database with one table for two (or more) entities with a many to  many relationship.
For instance, you might have an 'orders' table with multiple item columns (item_1, item_2, item_3).
To normalize the database we would

1. create a new TABLE for the 'items' and then
2. (this is were the question becomes relevant) relate the orders TABLE to the items TABLE through a linked TABLE called orders_items. This linked TABLE references the TABLES orders and items using FOREIGN KEYs. If the linking TABLE contains only the FOREIGN KEY to orders and items one problem will arise arise: The original orders table might have records where one order is related to a single item more than once. See below

```
-- original table to be normalized
order_id| item_1_id | item_1_name |item_2_id| item_2 |item_3_id | item_3
  1     |   3       | 'couch grey'| NULL    | NULL   |    NULL  | NULL
  2     |   2       |  'desk'     |   1     |'chair' |    1     | 'chair'
```

Looking at record with order_id 2, we see that there are two chairs related to this one order_id. The corresponding entry in the linked table would be

```
-- linking table
order_id| item_id   
  1     | 3
  2     | 2
  2     | 1
  2     | 1
```

This contains duplicate columns. To prevent this we can just add an orders_items id as a (syntetic) primary key:

```
-- linking table version 2
  id  | order_id| item_id
  1   |   1     | 3
  2   |   2     | 2
  3   |   2     | 1
  4   |   2     | 1
```

The new linking table accounts for orders with repeated items, but each record is unique so the table has no duplicates. For the orders_items id just define a new column with an autoincrement.

Below you find the implementation for PostgreSQL with the ROW_NUMBER() OVER function.

```
CREATE TABLE orders_items AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY order_id) AS id, *
  FROM
(SELECT order_id, item_1_id AS item_id
FROM store
UNION ALL
SELECT order_id, item_2_id
FROM store
WHERE item_2_id IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT order_id, item_3_id
FROM store
WHERE item_3_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY order_id) AS sq);
```