# How to create table structure in RDS similar to source table in Redshift and vice-versa

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds

Trying to automate table creation in database(RDS/Redshift) by using source table structure that is also present in either Redshift or RDS.

Database on which I am working on is RDS(mysql) and Redshift(postgresql).

**Approaches-**

1. Write all the mappings between data-types of RDS and Redshift, and handles all the edge cases.
2. Another way is by using any API/Library.

**Questions-**

I found "CREATE TABLE AS" in Redshift, but didn't get anything for RDS (MYSQL). Is there anything similar in RDS ?

Comment: Edit performed to your question. Not that I corrected all of it. Please don't ask for off-topic resource requests.

Comment: Try removing the `AS` and it should work on RDS

Comment: Will that create table structure as in Redshift ?

Comment: Amazon Data Migration Service ( https://aws.amazon.com/dms/ ) would be one choice