# SQL - Create a table from itself with new rows (insert into?)

Tags: sql

I want to create a table that will hold its currents rows and add new ones for each month but didn't find how to join the table with itself to get what I want.

Today I have a table with "current_records" from february
and a create table statement that get my values from february and do an union on another "current_month_table" to join all my records on a "all_records_table" so I get all my february+march records. But I don't want to create a new table for each month.

Tomorrow I'll want to have my "current_month_table" to list the april results and to append them to the existing "all_records_table" results.

I checked there [Create SQL table with the data from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382849/create-sql-table-with-the-data-from-another-table) as it seemed to provide good advice but I didnt get it to work.

```
CREATE TABLE `/Users/SQL essais/current_month_table` as c_m_t 
   INSERT INTO `/Users/SQL essais/all_records_table`  
    SELECT
            *
 FROM `/data`
```

the result was a full replacement of the data from current_month_table by the data from all_records_table where I wanted the data to go the other way around (and not replacing but adding rows).

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and you are using invalid standard SQL identifiers). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: Just a bit offtopic, but why do you need different tables for different months? Include date (or year + month number) field, fill it with current date (or year + month values) and just hold your data in single table.

Comment: only one table would suit me fine but I have to do my query on the same database every month where only few values change and I need to keep track of the changes.

Comment: In case you are using one table you can do something like this: `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE yearmonth_column = '201903'` (or `201904` for april). Looks easier than the current situation.

Comment: yes but I want to keep the records from previous yearmonth I don't want to keep only the latest. I want one big table with all the records, adding new row each month.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need an Insert-Select.

```
INSERT INTO all_records_table (Field1, Field2, Field3)
(SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM current_month_table)
```

You can add whatever joins and filters you need in the Select statement.
If you need more information, post additional examples of the data that is in the tables.